Try to Join tables while joining condition has on opertor getting details from in operator
LEFT JOIN #Phones P ON P.Phone_SID in (F.MobilePhone_SID, F.HomePhone_SID, F.OfficePhone_SID, F.PrimaryPhone_SID, F.SecondaryPhone_SID)
cani write this into
Left jion #Phones P ON P.Phone_SID = F.MobilePhone_SID and P.Phone_SID =F.HomePhone_SID and P.Phone_SID =F.ScondaryPhone_SID
correct or wrong of my assumption

Instead of and use or

If you use
Left join #Phones P ON P.Phone_SID = F.MobilePhone_SID and P.Phone_SID =F.HomePhone_SID and P.Phone_SID =F.ScondaryPhone_SID

you are requiring P.Phone_SID to equal all three of Mobile, phone and HomePhone - which is highly unlikely. You want P.Phone_SID to be ONE OF F.MobilePhone_SID, F.HomePhone_SID, F.ScondaryPhone_SID - you need to write that as
Left join #Phones P ON P.Phone_SID = F.MobilePhone_SID OR P.Phone_SID =F.HomePhone_SID OR P.Phone_SID =F.ScondaryPhone_SID

Note the corrected spelling of join as well
